# Running android's sqlite3 using process and/or runtime

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm currently working on an android project that needs to run sqlite3 the way you run it in a terminal. With that I used the following method:

Using Runtime exec() method:

```
private void startProcess(String cmd){

    //ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("echo hello world");
    //processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try {
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sqlite3 ", cmd});
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            String result = "";

            @Override
            public void run() {

                String line;

                try {
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                        result += line + "\n";
                    }

                    reader.close();
                    process.getInputStream().close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("response", result);

            }
        }).start();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Using Process Builder :

```
     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startProcess(new String[]{"sqlite3", code_area.getText().toString()});
        }
    });

}

private void startProcess(String[] cmd){

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try {
        final Process process = processBuilder.start();
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            String result = "";

            @Override
            public void run() {

                String line;

                try {
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                        result += line + "\n";
                    }

                    reader.close();
                    process.getInputStream().close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("response", result);

            }
        }).start();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Both method did not return any results nor thrown any error in logcat.

Now, my question is, 1) What is it not returning an result nor throwing error if there is,
2) Is there any other method to run sqlite3 the way you run it in a terminal?
and 3) Is there any logical error that I'm missing to notice?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

I'm using emulator to test the project and haven't tried it yet on a real device.

Comment: I do not think that the `sqlite3` command-line binary is necessarily installed on all Android devices. On those devices where it is installed, it may not be in the `PATH` and may not be in a consistent location.

Comment: Why do you need to run it that way?  What do you think you can accomplish that way you can't accomplish with more standard techniques?

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan my projects aims to let the users execute sql queries in a "terminal", and by standard techniques, you mean SQLiteDatabase or SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: Yes.  You can always just pass the user's queries in via rawQuery().  I'm going to assume you know the dangers of allowing users to directly query the db and that you accept them.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan , I'll consider this option.