# Executing sqlite meta commands

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my little knowledge about android-sqlite, android's SQLiteDatabase class only executes CRUD operations. Now my question is, is it possible to execute sqlite dot-commands (special commands) in SQLiteStatement, like `sqlite .databases` ?

Comment: try `db.rawQuery("select * from sqlite_master", null)` (though i never tested on the device)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have "meta commands".

SQLite understands [SQL commands](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).
The [`sqlite3` command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) implements additional dot commands; if you want to use them elsewhere, you have to call `sqlite3` (if it is available), or implement them yourself.

Comment: I tried to do this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329154/running-androids-sqlite3-using-process-and-or-runtime) but it does not work with me as well, that question does not have any good answers.

Comment: On Android, `sqlite3` often is not available.

Comment: I tried to access sqlite3 using terminal emulator that I installed in emulator, I even found out that it is stored in /system/xbin. Now when I try use it using the terminal, it works fine but when I use it using from java, that's where the problem arise.

Comment: How to start an external process would be a different question.

Answer (score -1):

By meta commands do you mean DDL (data description language, commands that create, alter, etc tables)?  Or things like pragma commands?  In either case, the answer is yes.  Just use `database.rawQuery()`

Comment: On many devices the sqlite command line utility is installed, so you can run that and pipe command in.  But it isn't universal.

Comment: Hi, I searched some example and most examples have this ProcessBuilder which I am not familiar with, Is it too much if I ask for an example of pipe command?